# Call method with function as argument of Cocoa Touch Framework (swift) from Single View Application (objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, function

I created `Cocoa Touch Framework` in `swift` (called MyFramework). In MyFramework I have method which requires functions as arguments. In short hand **MyFramework** contains this code:

```
public class MyFramework : NSObject {
    public func MyMethod(successCallback : (String) -> Void, errorCallback : (String, String) -> Void) -> Void {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            // successCallback("some value");
            // errorCallback("error reason", "error message");
        });
    }
}
```

I can include `MyFramework` in `Single View Application` called `MyAppSwift` (in `swift`) and successfully call **MyMethod** of MyFramework in `ViewController.swift` by this code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let myframework : MyFramework = MyFramework();

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        myframework.MyMethod(self.onSuccess, errorCallback : self.onError);
    }

    private func onSuccess(value : String) {
        // ... 
    }

    private func onError(reason : String, error : String) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I can include `MyFramework` in `Single View Application` called `MyAppObjectiveC` (in objective-c) but I do not know how to call `MyMethod` of MyFramework in `ViewController.m` ...

```
// In ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MyFramework/MyFramework.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyFramework * myframework;
- (void) onSuccess : (NSString *) value;
- (void) onError : (NSString *) reason : (NSString *) error;
@end
```

.

```
// In ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.myframework = [[MyFramework alloc] init];
    [self.myframework MyMethod : self onSuccess, self onError];
}
- (void) onSuccess : (NSString *) value {
    // ...
}
- (void) onError : (NSString *) reason : (NSString *) error {
    // ...
}

@end
```

This line **[self.myframework MyMethod : self onSuccess, self onError];** is not working. Xcode says expecting identifier ":" after onSuccess and then expects expresion. Im not sure what to insert. I read several answers on stackoverflow how to pass method as argument in objective-c but no success. For example I have tried selectors **[self.myframework MyMethod : @selector(onSuccess:), @selector(onError::)];** but Xcode says: "Sending 'SEL' to parameter of incompatible type 'void(^_Nonnull)(NSString * _Nonnull __strong)'

Comment: In file MyFramework.framework/Headers/MyFramework-Swift.h i see that MyMethod is declared in objective-c as: **- (void)MyMethod:(void (^ _Nonnull)(NSString * _Nonnull))successCallback;** (without errorCallback) and second alternative: **- (void)MyMethod:(void (^ _Nonnull)(NSString * _Nonnull))successCallback errorCallback:(void (^ _Nonnull)(NSString * _Nonnull, NSString * _Nonnull))errorCallback;**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out, according to the `*-Swift.h`header Swift's `MyMethod` is imported into Objective-C as taking *blocks* as arguments.  So, you need to pass it blocks that wrap the Objective-C method calls, something like this:

```
[self.myframework MyMethod: ^ (NSString * s){ [self onSuccess:s]; }
       errorCallback: ^(NSString * s1, NSString * s2) { [self onError:s1:s2]; }];
```

See here for more info about Objective-C blocks: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Comment: Thank you OmniProg! It works great! Just detail... errorCallback "[self onError:s1 reason:s2]" should be [self onError:s1 error:s2] ? However, I had to write just "[self onError:s1:s2]" (without keys) because xcode said "No visible @interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector 'onError:error:'".

Comment: Sorry, made the correction.  In fact, the compiler is absolutely right, as usual: in order for the selector to be `onError:s1 error:s2`, the function would have to be `- (void) onError : (NSString *) reason error : (NSString *) error`